# Building .net framework version 4 using msbuild

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, .net-framework-version

I am working on CI pipeline for a .Net framework version 4. I am using msbuild to build the project. I am new to .net so not sure how to build the project.
below are the folders and files in my project

- appservices
- .gitignore
- .gitlab-ci.yml
- errorlog.txt
- appservices.sln

below is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
    variable:
      MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:/Program Files(x86)/MSBUILD/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe'
    stages:
      - Build
    Code Build
      tags:
        - dotnet-runner
    stage- Build
    script:
     - $MSBuild_PATH /p:configuration=Release /clp:ErrorOnly
```

I got below error running my build job

```
  + $MSBuild_PATH /p:configuration=Release /clp:ErrorOnly
  +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Unexpected token '/p:configuration=Release' /clp:ErrorOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs this flag should be `-p` rather than `/p`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019